# Adding views to window a second time not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a view (View1) that is initially laid out on the right side of the screen with a tableview to its left, both pinned to the outer edges of a content view.  I am trying to support animating View 1 fullscreen while also overlaying another view on top of it to provide some controls like exiting fullscreen.

I am able to programmatically store off the constraints and frame of the content view associated with View1, add View1 to Window's view, and then add the overlay view on top of it without a problem.  I am also able to support exiting fullscreen, which removes the overlay view, adds View1 back to the original content view, and restores the stored off View1 frame and constraints to the content view.  That works great.  Trying to go fullscreen a second time, however, does not work.  View1 is not visible and the overlay view is only partially visible.

These views all have the proper size anytime I can think to print them out, including viewDidLayoutSubviews.  Inspecting the views after everything is laid out, I see View1 has a zero-height, and the overlay view is collapsed to only fit its child subviews.

I suspect autolayout at play and hoping I'm just missing something on the exit-fullscreen.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: My code to move a view fullscreen is:

```
// View1
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.contentView.constraints) {
    if (constraint.firstItem == self.imageView || constraint.secondItem == self.imageView) {
        [self.nonFullscreenConstraints addObject:constraint];
    }
}
self.nonFullscreenFrame = self.imageView.frame;
[self.view.window addSubview:self.imageView];
[self.view.window bringSubviewToFront:self.imageView];
self.imageView.frame = self.view.window.frame;

// Overlay
[self.view.window addSubview:self.fullscreenOverlayView];
[self.view.window bringSubviewToFront:self.fullscreenOverlayView];
self.fullscreenOverlayView.frame = self.view.window.frame;
```

And my code to exit fullscreen is:

```
// View1
self.imageView.frame = self.nonFullscreenFrame;
self.nonFullscreenFrame = CGRectZero;
[self.contentView addSubview:self.imageView];
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in self.nonFullscreenConstraints) {
    [self.contentView addConstraint:constraint];
}
[self.nonFullscreenConstraints removeAllObjects];

// Overlay
[self.fullscreenOverlayView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: I suspect one problem is that you change the view hierarchy prior to changing constraints. Removing a view I believe removes any constraints. You should probably make a copy of the constraints first, then move the view, then apply the constraints and last layoutIfNeeded.

Comment: That's what I have in the first for loop under View1.  I don't store the Overlay constraints as that one just needs to go full screen and it's just floating until I need it.

Comment: If you break point before and after those loops can you confirm that the correct constraints are being applied?

Comment: Just confirmed constraints are exactly the same for View1.  Behavior with the view is as expected, too.

Answer (score 0):

Identified the problem. I wasn't adding the overlay view back to the original parent and restoring the constraints the same way I was View1.  After doing that, I can pop in and out of fullscreen as expected.